# Importing anything from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` always returns null

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2, typescript2.0, angular-material2

I'm trying to get Angular's material2 library setup. The issue I'm running with is none of the animations work. Any time I import *anything* from `@angular/platform-browser/animations`, it always returns null.

I'm using the following dependencies in `package.json` -

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.2.5"
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.5"
```

Here is how I'm importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` (as per the documentation) -

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

However, attempting to importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` into my root `AppModule`, I receive an Angular about importing null, which I was able to verify by simply outputting `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the console.

I am getting a warning with webpack that I'm unable to figure out -

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/animations.d.ts
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) [at-loader] TypeScript declaration files should never be required
```

Answer (score -1):

Install angular animations

```
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

in your app module

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: This module is installed like mentioned in the question. 

I would expect an error about module not being found otherwise.

Comment: Clear your package cache using npm cache clean and install packages again